# Does drools support statement like 'group by' in SQL?

Tags: drools

I have read drools documents about `accumulate` function, there is a function called `collectSet`, but it only returns `List` rather than `Map`. What I want to do is something like `group by` in sql statement. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: More over, I have tried to implement `org.kie.api.runtime.rule.AccumulateFunction` as the document proposed, but there is problem: in order to implement function `void accumulate(Serializable context,
                    Object value);`, I am confusing that variable `value` is not a `Fact`, so that this way doesn't work for me.

Comment: Your accumulate function could return `Map<X,List<Y>>`, X being the group key. Then you'll have to process this Map, using some (Java) code. Is that what you want?

Comment: @laune thank you!  I think this is slow because it should go through all data twice? I hope it could work just like built-in function such as `sum` or `average` function : `$avgProfit : average( 1 - $cost / $price ) `.

Comment: Well, if you need the sums or averages for each group you can make that in one pass. -- Why don't you say what you really need, not "something like" this or that?

Answer (score -1):

Drools 8.41.0.Final and later now support groupby. It has the following syntax:

`groupby(source-pattern; grouping-key; accumulators [; constraints])`

Where:

- `source-pattern`: Pattern used to gather facts that will be grouped and accumulated. For instance, using `$a: /applicants[age < 21]` as the `source-pattern` would group and accumulate all Applicants under the age of 21 (binding the applicant to `$a`, which can be used in the grouping-key and accumulators)
- `grouping-key`: A function used to divide the `source-pattern` into separate groups. Facts from `source-pattern` for which `grouping-key` returns the same value are grouped together. The key can optionally be bound to a variable, allowing it to be used outside the `groupby`. For example, using `$country: $a.country` as the grouping key would group applicants by country, binding the country for the group to the `$country` variable.
- `accumulators`: One or more accumulate functions used to accumulate the facts in each group. Each accumulate function can optionally be bound to a variable, allowing it to be used outside the `groupby`. For instance, `$count: count()` would count the number of applicants younger than 21 from each country.
- `constraints`: Optional constraints on the group key and accumulation result. The rest of the rule will only execute for the given group key if all constraints return `true`. For instance, `$count >= 100` would only continue execution of the rule for a given `$country` if that country have at least 100 applicants younger than 21.

Combining the above example together, we get:

```
groupby(
    $a: /applicants[age < 21];
    $country: $a.country;
    $count: count();
    $count >= 100
)
```

Which says "Collect the number of applicants under the age of 21 by country for countries with at least 100 applicants".

As an example of a complete rule, here is a rule that get the highest bid of a product:

```
rule "Highest bid for a product"
    groupby($bid: /bids;
            $product: $bid.product;
            $highestBid: max($bid)
    )
then
    // do something with $highestBid and $product
end
```

The examples given used the OOPath syntax, but the [traditional syntax is also supported](https://docs.drools.org/8.39.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/language-reference/index.html#new-and-traditional-syntax_drl-rules).